# Is there a command that would allow me to rename a directory only if it had a certain amount of digits together?

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a directory that has many sub-directories in them. Basically, I am wondering if there is a way to delete all the words in the folders, and only leave the digits in the folder name that are placed together in a series of 6.

For example:

Folder name before -> Example 1 123456

Folder name after -> 123456

I was able to use a filter to delete spaces, characters, and single digits using powershell. It looks like this.

This didn't work when I tried it a while back because when I tried to remove single digits it was leaving blank folders or folders with only a single digit. I was wondering if someone would be gracious enough to assist me, a point in the right direction would be great as I do like to learn.

Thank you!

````
while($true){
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Write-Host "Renaming Directories in Job CLoud to Delete the Letters and Unwanted Characters, Please do not disrupt this service..."
cd -Path "C:\Users\run\Desktop\testing"
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "a","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "b","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "c","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "d","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "e","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "f","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "g","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "h","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "i","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "j","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "k","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "l","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "m","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "n","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "o","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "p","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "q","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "r","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "s","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "t","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "u","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "v","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "w","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "x","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "y","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "z","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "A","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "B","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "C","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "D","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "E","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "F","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "G","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "H","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "I","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "J","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "K","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "L","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "M","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "N","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "O","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "P","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "Q","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "R","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "S","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "T","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "U","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "V","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "W","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "X","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "Y","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "Z","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "!","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "/","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "$","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "-","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "'","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "_","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "t","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "T","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "t ","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "T ","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace " t","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace " T","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "# ","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace " #","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "#","") + $_.Extension }
Get-Item *| Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace " ","") + $_.Extension }


}```
````

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use regular expressions to match a pattern of six consecutive digits rather than trying to handle every non-digit character one at a time.

e.g.

```
$Values = @('a123456', 'a 123412', '21 413 512312')

$Values | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '\d{6}'){
        $Matches[0]
    }
}
```

$Matches automatically stores the result of -match.

\d{6} means six consecutive digits.

Once you have the match, all you need to do is handle what happens when you don't find six digits, and rename-item.

Answer (score 1):

This will check the names of 'C:\TestFolder' subfolders for 6 digits and if matched will rename the folder to those 6 digits (contained in automatic variable $Matches when using -match operator)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\TestFolder' -Directory | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\d{6}' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $Matches.Values[0] } -WhatIf
```